# React serverside rendering pointing to wrong bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I have a react server-side rendering application along with node & express js.

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Test from './Test';

export default () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/test/:deviceId" component={Test} />
        </div>

    );
};
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import renderer from './helpers/renderer';


const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.send(renderer(req));
});

app.listen(3090, () => {
    console.log('listening at http://localhost:3090');
})
```

**renderer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from '../components/Routes';

export default req => {
  const content = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={{}}>
      <Routes />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">${content}</div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

**client.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Well,  I am trying to pass a deviceId along with my route /test/:deviceId,
and my HTML template under renderer.js looks for bundle.js file under /test/build.js instead of /bundle.js

How do I make sure my bundle file always points to the correct location which is under **public** folder exposed by

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

if I visit, / route to Home component, it looks for bundle.js under correct folder which is the public folder.

Do let me know if you need any extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I have figured out what was changing the path of bundle.js with each out.

if my route is `'/'`, it will look for bundle.js at `http://localhost:3090/bundle.js`

if the route is `'/test/:deviceId'`, it will look for bundle.js at `http://localhost:3090/test/:deviceId/bundle.js` (in this scenario it will never find bundle.js)

I fixed it my modifying the html temlate under renderer.js

for the  tag I changed path to bundle.js from `'bundle.js'` to `'/bundle.js'`

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from '../components/Routes';

export default req => {
  const content = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={{}}>
      <Routes />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">${content}</div>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

Now, it will always look for bundle.js under `http://localhost:3090/bundle.js`